# back button is not working in form of codenameone

Tags: forms, codenameone

I have created a form from UIdesign in which a button is added .
I have added action listener on that button which display new Form (developed  by code)

```
Form newform = new Form("new form");
newform.show();
```

My problem is when i click on back button,  the previous form is not displayed
how can the previous form be displayed on clicking back button ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GUI builder you should use `showForm("FormName", null)` otherwise you need to handle form navigation on your own by implementing the back command.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding
I am not adding any button in newform .
I want to go previous by clicking back button of mobile device
How to handle the default back button of device in codenameone (by code or gui builder)